# Is a Jew allowed to marry a non-observant Jew?

Tags: halacha, marriage, non-religious

Is a Jew allowed to marry another Jew who is generally unconcerned with observing Judaism?

On one hand, the first Jew's observance could be negatively affected by the second Jew's non-observance, and there could be other complications in the marriage if there are differing observance levels. On the other hand, marrying another Jew ensures that the non-observant Jew won't marry a non-Jew and produce non-Jewish or assimilated Jewish descendants.

Comment: See https://www.inn.co.il/News/News.aspx/365338 בפרק ו' דנים המחברים בהיתר לבחור או בחורה להינשא לבחיר/ת ליבם שאינו/ה שומר/ת מצוות. אחרי הבאת הצדדים השונים לעניין זה, והדגשת חשיבות בניין בית יהודי כשר, הם מכריעים: "ראוי להימנע ככל האפשר. עם זאת, כאשר קיים מצע משותף של אמונה ומחויבות בסיסית להלכה, אין צורך לדקדק בציציותיו של בן הזוג". לענ"ד זוהי מסקנה מזעזעת. יש כאן היתר מפורש לשאת בן זוג או בת זוג שאינם מחויבים ממש לשמירת מצוות, בלי לשים לב להשלכות החמורות שהדבר עלול להביא לעתידו של בן הזוג שומר המצוות ולעתיד ילדיו... כך לא בונים בית המבוסס על התורה והמצוות!

Comment: And https://ravtzair.blogspot.com/2018/02/blog-post.html כעסו של הרב קטן על היתר זה, העלול לדעתו לפגוע בעתיד הרוחני של בן-הזוג המקפיד יותר, משקף אטימות מסוימת כלפי מצוקת הרווקות-המאוחרת בציבור הדתי-לאומי. דווקא מי שחשוב לו לשמור על מוסד המשפחה, ולא להזדקק לפתרונות דחוקים כמו הפריה של רווקות, ראוי לו להיות קשוב יותר למצוקה זו. אכן לכתחילה ראוי לכל אדם לחפש בן-זוג ששאיפותיו הרוחניות הולמות במדויק את אלו שלו. אך במציאות המורכבת והמגוונת שבה אנו חיים, דרישה כזו היא פעמים רבות בלתי-אפשרית ואף מופרכת.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As cited above, the Shulchan Aruch advises against it. The Mishna in Kesubos talks about divorce if it's discovered that a spouse is non-observant, and/or the non-observance is affecting the observant spouse. (More on that in a moment.)

Let's start with two important points here:

- Never go into a marriage thinking "I am saving this person from something worse."
- Never go into a marriage thinking "I am going to change this person."

(Let's also remember the Gemara says don't go into a marriage that is likely to lead to resentment; "love your neighbor like yourself" applies to your spouse too.)

---

Rabbi Mordechai Willig shlit"a has a YUTorah mp3 on *Kibud Av V'em* where he addresses the obligation of respect (broadly) towards a non-observant parent. In the course of that, he remarks: *Chazal also say you have to respect your spouse. Today it would be scandalous, but not long ago it was not uncommon -- suppose one spouse is observant and the other isn't; does that mean he doesn't have to respect her (or vice versa?)*

---

The really big questions that will need to be asked are how the kids will be raised, and what about things that affect the other spouse -- most notably "family purity" and "is the food in our kitchen kosher?" (This can get a drop trickier when we address the question of "can I trust a person who doesn't keep kosher to keep my plates kosher?")

Long story short: it's generally not the greatest idea, but with a lot of agreement and planning, it could be doable. There doesn't seem to be a clear thou-shalt-not against it. The least-problematic scenario would be something like a second marriage in which the kids are out of the house and Nida is no longer a biological concern.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Halacha in the Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 2,6

> לעולם ישתדל אדם לישא בת תלמיד חכם ולהשיא בתו לתלמיד חכם. לא מצא בת תלמיד חכם, ישא בת גדולי הדור. לא מצא בת גדולי הדור, ישא בת ראשי כנסיות. לא מצא בת ראשי כנסיות, ישא בת גבאי צדקה. לא מצא בת גבאי צדקה, ישא בת מלמדי תינוקות, ואל ישיא בתו לעם הארץ:
>    הגה: ועל בנותיהן הוא אומר: ארור שוכב עם בהמה. וכל זה בעם הארץ שאינו מדקדק במצוות

Basically there is a whole list of preferred Jewish girls and it is seriously not recommended to marry a woman from a non orthodox background **who acts like her background** (it is not in your power to change someone as they were given free will) unless of course she now keeps the Mitzvot in which case it is perfectly fine.*

*ולא בכל עם הארץ אלא במי שהוא חשוד לעבור
The Tur Beit Yosef says that this only applies to those who are suspect to transgressing Mitzvot.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone can achieve a return or teshuva to G-'s holy name. With that I'm mind, it's not advisable to marry someone secular, as that return to HK"B has not happened yet.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Maybe it is the reverse - maybe marrying the person is the best way to help him/her accomplish *tshuva*? How would one know when answering the question in general terms?

Comment: @mbloch I have heard from many Torah minded marriage experts in the name of Gedolim that one should never marry someone with the intention of changing that person's ways. Especially when it means to change them in ruchaniyus.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you think this is the case, where you’re getting this from?